# How to define custom content entity one to many relationship?

Tags: 8, entities, database

I have two custom entities; `A`, `B`.

In terms of database relationships, I want `A` to have many `B`.

I find I am able to define a `reference_entity` field in the entity's `baseFieldDefinition()`. However, because this just defines a single column in the database my relationships are back to front:

I can give `B` a reference to `A` and then use `$B->getEntity()->referencedEntities()` to get a `B`'s associated `A`, but I can't do it the other way round because there's just a single id for each row.

Is there a correct way to query or set up these kinds of relationships 'out-the-box' or is a better solution to add my own method to the `A` entity `getReferencedBs()` and query the `B` table for references to `A`.

Many thanks

Comment: I think that you should create your custom method that uses a query.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add setCardinality(-1) to your B reference field definition in your A entity. This will change the B reference field to support an unlimited number of references instead of 1, the default cardinality.